# Should I use "have been", "has been" or "being" in this case?

Tags: sentence-construction

> The project requires more people than being put in because it is extremely difficult.
>
> The project requires more people than has been put in because it is extremely difficult.
>
> The project requires more people than have been put in because it is extremely difficult.

May I know which of these is correct and the reason behind it?

Comment: The project requires more people than those currently employed/ deployed because it is extremely difficult.

Comment: [People is plural in English.]

Answer (score 1):

> The project requires more people than have been put in because it is extremely difficult.

The answer is "have been" because people is plural.

"They have been". "He has been".

Next,

"than have been put in" is implied, and could be omitted:

> The project requires more people, because it is extremely difficult.

If you do wish to include "than..." it might convey more specific meaning, such as:

> The project requires more people than have been assigned to it so far, because it is extremely difficult.
>
> The project requires more people than have been recruited so far, because it is extremely difficult.